# How can i use correctly processbuilder with shp2pgsql

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, postgis

Well i did a lot of research about import and export shapefile into postgis using java code.I tried to use shp2pgsql with processBuilder but it doesn't work for me.
When i run the code it gives me no error.

His is the code I've been using:

```
   String userName="postgres";
   String path="A:\\DATA\\Provinces.shp";
   String table="test";
   String txtDB="test";
   String cmd =  " shp2pgsql –I –D -W \\LATIN1\\ "+path+" "+table+" | psql -  p 5432 "+txtDB+" "+ userName;

   String[] command = { "cmd","/c","C:\\Program   Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.2\\bin\\shp2pgsql.exe",cmd };

    ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    final Process process = probuilder.start();


    //Read out dir output
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

   //Wait to get exit value
    try {
        int exitValue = process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("\n\nExit Value is " + exitValue);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ProcessBuilder pb= new ProcessBuilder();
    pb.command("shp2pgsql ","<filepath>|psql -U postgres");
    Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;

    String temp="";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        temp=temp.concat(line);
        System.out.println("shp2pgsql: " + line);
    }
    if(!temp.isEmpty())
    {
        PreparedStatement preStmt=con.prepareStatement(temp);
        preStmt.executeUpdate();
        return true;
    }
```